# How to import the types of react-dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dropzone

I'm using [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) with typescript, but I don't know how to import the types off react-dropzone. I could not find it in the documentation. What is the type of rejectedFiles?

Code example

```
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isFocused, isDragAccept, isDragReject } = useDropzone({
    onDropRejected,
  })

const onDropRejected = useCallback(rejectedFiles => {
    setFilesRejected(rejectedFiles)
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the type, and declare your state with this type: `FileRejection[]`

```
import { FileRejection } from 'react-dropzone';
```